# How can i sort a zipped list based on conditions?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'am trying to sort a zipped list based on the value. So the list is something like this

`[('Job 1', '3', '1'), ('Job 2', '1', '3'), ('Job 3', '2', '3'),('Job 4', '4', '3')]`

What I want to do is to sort the list based on the value of the index `[1]` and `[2]`. For example:

```
Job 1         3         1
Job 2         1         3
Job 3         2         3
Job 4         4         3
```

If the value in column 2 is smaller than column 3, the table would become:

```
Job 2         1         3
Job 3         2         3
Job 1         3         1
Job 4         4         3
```

I have been searching for the method but it seems like a dead end. So far what I found is just `sort()` the whole list based on the index.

Comment: you should post the code that you have tried yet.

Comment: It looks like you might be interested in using pandas for your task. I'd also recommend that whatever method you use, you convert all your numeric columns to numbers before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

You could just `sort` it by using the `keyfunc` that returns  `index 1` and `index 2` item converted to `int`,

```
>>> x
[('Job 1', '3', '1'), ('Job 2', '1', '3'), ('Job 3', '2', '3'), ('Job 4', '4', '3')]
>>> sorted(x, key=lambda x: (int(x[1]), int(x[2])))
[('Job 2', '1', '3'), ('Job 3', '2', '3'), ('Job 1', '3', '1'), ('Job 4', '4', '3')]
>>> y = _
>>> for i in x:
...   print(i)
... 
('Job 1', '3', '1')
('Job 2', '1', '3')
('Job 3', '2', '3')
('Job 4', '4', '3')
>>> for j in y:
...   print(j)
... 
('Job 2', '1', '3')
('Job 3', '2', '3')
('Job 1', '3', '1')
('Job 4', '4', '3')
>>>
```